# TextString@NumberForm for large integer

Tags: bugs, output-formatting

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.4**

---

A curiosity really, but why do I get garbage here?

```
TextString@NumberForm[3 10^23, 24]
```

> 300000000000000008388608.

And why does the output even have a decimal point?

Even more strange if we do this sequentially we get the expected result.

```
 NumberForm[3 10^23, 24]
```

> 300000000000000000000000

```
 TextString[%]
```

> 300000000000000000000000

This shows up in `StringTemplate` as well since `TextString` is the default `InsertionFunction`

V 10.1 / windows 7 64 bit and linux same issue.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem (either `10.4.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)` or `11.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 18, 2017)`). What version and OS are you using?

Comment: v 10.1 / windows.

Comment: Is your Windows 32-bit or 64-bit? You will need someone with the same OS to verify.

Comment: I cannot reproduce [your question](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4ciX.png).

Comment: Versions 10.4.0 through 11.1.0 give the correct result on 64-bit Linux; however, versions 10.2.0 and 10.3.1 show the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this bug has been fixed as of version 10.4.0.

```
TextString@NumberForm[3 10^23, 24]

(* "300000000000000000000000" *)
```